# Create a PL/SQL block to insert a new record into the Department table

Tags: oracle, plsql

My question is

> Create a PL/SQL block to insert a new record into the Department table. Fetch the maximum department id from the Department table and add 10 to it; take this value for department id; 'TESTING' is the value for department name and CHN-102 is the value for Location ID.

I coded like this:

```
BEGIN
select max(DEPARTMENT_ID)+10
 INTO DEPARTMENT_ID
 FROM Department 
 INSERT INTO Department (DEPARTMENT_NAME,LOCATION_ID) VALUES ('TESTING','CHN-102');
END;
/
```

but an error is coming like

```
INSERT INTO Department (DEPARTMENT_NAME,LOCATION_ID) VALUES ('TESTING','CHN-102'
);                                                                              
*                                                                               
ERROR at line 5:                                                                
ORA-06550: line 4, column 17:                                                   
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended                               
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:                                                    
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

How to approach to solve this homework? Please help me

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you didn't declare a variable you'll store a new department ID into
- select statement misses the terminator (semi-colon)
- if you put that effort into finding the ID, why didn't you insert it?

When fixed, code you might be looking for then looks like this:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM department;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME      LOCATION_I
------------- -------------------- ----------
            2

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_department_id  department.department_id%TYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT MAX (department_id) + 10 INTO l_department_id FROM department;
  5
  6     INSERT INTO department (department_id, department_name, location_id)
  7          VALUES (l_department_id, 'TESTING', 'CHN-102');
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM department;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME      LOCATION_I
------------- -------------------- ----------
            2
           12 TESTING              CHN-102

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Department 
(DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,LOCATION_ID) 
select max(DEPARTMENT_ID)+10,'TESTING','CHN-102'
from Department;

END;
/
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.